# Released unknown imageData reference on map.clear()

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to plot multiple markers fetched from server and then removing them on some event and then plotting them back on pressing cancel button. Everytime I call

```
map.clear()
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Released unknown imageData reference`
```

This is how I am adding markers (by calling plot_all_markers method) after getting details from server

```
 try {
         for (int i = 0; i < Constant.spot_details.size(); i++) {
              LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(Constant.spot_details.get(i).geo_x),
              Double.parseDouble(Constant.spot_details.get(i).geo_y));
              final MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latlng);

              if (Constant.spot_details.get(i).type.equals("a")) {
                  marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.a_marker));
              } else if (Constant.spot_details.get(i).type.equals("b")) {
                  marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.b_marker_grey));
              } else
                  marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(Utils.string_to_bitmap(Constant.spot_details.get(i).logo, activity)));

                  marker.title(Constant.spot_details.get(i).name);
                  final Marker m=mMap.addMarker(marker);
                  all_markers.add(m);
                  animate_marker_fade_in(m);
                  plotted_spot_array.add(Constant.spot_details.get(i));
                  marker_map.put(marker.getPosition().latitude + marker.getPosition().longitude, i);
              }
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

This how I am removing markers from map and plotting only one needed marker

```
mMap.clear();
    PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    String s = "";
    latLngs = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    try {
        //  s = result.getString("points");
        s = Constant.request_spot.directions[0].overview_polyline.points;
        latLngs = decodePoly(s);
        s = "";
        LatLng latLong = new LatLng(0, 0);
        for (LatLng l : latLngs) {
            lineOptions.add(l);
            s = l.latitude + ", " + s;
            latLong = l;
        }
        lineOptions.width(5);
        lineOptions.color(R.color.theme_color);
        _m = Demand.mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.a_marker_yellow)));
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        builder.include(new LatLng(Constant.request_spot.directions[0].legs[0].start_location.lat,
                Constant.request_spot.directions[0].legs[0].start_location.lng));
        builder.include(new LatLng(Constant.request_spot.directions[0].legs[0].end_location.lat,
                Constant.request_spot.directions[0].legs[0].end_location.lng));
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        int padding = 300; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
        Demand.mMap.animateCamera(cu);
        Demand.mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        cross_item.setVisible(true);
```

Lastly on pressing cross_item I am again calling mMap.clear(), but its crashing on that line

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_filter) {
        mMap.clear();
        cross_item.setVisible(false);
        plot_all_markers();
        requestServer(mMap.getCameraPosition().target);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is my Logcat output

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Released unknown imageData reference
at maps.ce.i.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.ei.bh.c(Unknown Source)
at maps.ei.s.o(Unknown Source)
at maps.ei.bu.e(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.e$a.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.alldynamite:205)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.clear(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.clear(Unknown Source)
at com.drishtigroup.needtopark.fragments.Demand.onOptionsItemSelected(Demand.java:499)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:2085)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2163)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentController.java:304)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:410)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:167)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:69)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:169)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:760)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:618)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:139)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: What kind of object is `cross_item`? Is it map related?

Comment: @antonio- its a simple menuitem. On tapping of that menuitem I am calling map.clear()

Answer (score 0):

`IllegalArgumentException` means that the
exception that indicates the arguments supplied to a method or function are not valid for their intended purpose, or are different to the format expected by the method.

In this [github issue](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/189) they fix the error IllegalArgumentException: Released unknown imageData reference, by using cluster manager in clearing the markers. It's suggest here that never clear the markers straight from the map itself but use the cluster manager in clearing and adding the markers.

```
mClusterManager.clearItems();
mClusterManager.addItems(mMapVenueItems);
mClusterManager.cluster();
```

I hope it can help you with your problem.

Comment: I am not using clusters in my application. Do you still think ClusterManager is preferable to use?